# Splitting a Django project

Tags: python, django, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a django project with various apps, which are completely independent. I'd like to make them run each one in their own process, as some of them spawn background threads to precalculate periodically some data and now they are competing for the CPU (the machine has loads of cores, but you know, the GIL and such...)

So, is there an easy way to split automatically the project into different ones, or at least to make each app live in its own process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always have different settings files, but that would be like having multiple projects and even multiple endpoints. With some effort you could configure a reverse proxy to forward to the right Django server, based on the request's path and so on, but I don't think that's what you want and it would be an ugly solution to your problem.

The solution to this is to move the heavy processing to a jobs queue. A lot of people and projects prefer [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) for this.

If that seems like overkill for some reason, you can always implement your own based on simple cron jobs. You can take a look at [my small project](https://github.com/alexandru/django-asynctasks) that does this.

Comment: Celery was an option that I came upon while googling a solution to my problem, I think it might be worth to look into it :-)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest of the simple is probably to write a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-management-commands/) that observes given model (database table) for new entries and processes them. The model is written to by e.g. Django view and the management command is launched periodically from cron (e.g. every 5 minutes).

Example: user registers on the site, but the account creation is an expensive operation (allocating some space, pinging remote services etc.). Therefore you just write a new record to AccountRequest table (`AccountRequest.objects.create(...)`). Then, cron periodically launches your management script (`./manage.py account_creator`), which checks for new AccountRequest-s (`AccountRequest.objects.filter(unprocessed=True)`), does its job and marks those requests as processed.

Comment: This works and I also did it like this, but you may run into problems because race conditions can happen, which is why I prefer a more general purpose solution that has this small feat figured out.

Comment: @Alexandru: What kind of race condition do you mean?

Comment: Tomasz, background jobs are by definition slow and unpredictable and cron.d does not care about that. At one point I ended up in a situation in which the original process started was too slow to finish in the allocated X minutes, so cron kept starting processes, which brought my server to a complete halt eventually :-) ... this and also the possibility of having 2 processes that are processing the same data which then opens another can of worms. So some care must be taken to ensure these 2 things don't happen.

Comment: Ah, good point. But that's trivial to fix - use a [lockfile](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65203/). The snippet looks ugly but under Linux you only need the [fcntl.lockf()](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.lockf) part.